# Reproducible numbers in Keras/TensorFlow

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, keras, reproducible-research

Every time I run a Keras/TensorFlow code gives different results. Can someone suggest how to get reproducible numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to set the random seed.

Theano mostly uses numpy for pRNG.

```
from numpy.random import seed
seed(1)
```

In Tensorflow, things are a bit more complicated

```
from numpy.random import seed
seed(1)
from tensorflow import set_random_seed
set_random_seed(2)
```

More information: https://machinelearningmastery.com/reproducible-results-neural-networks-keras/